# Can I install/run multiple copies of a flatpak app?

Tags: flatpak

Is it possible to install or run multiple copies of a flatpack package (example: Teams), each with its own isolated copy?

Comment: Tried with snap and worked like a charm. But I'd like to use flatpak.

Comment: You shouldn't tag this as "snap" unless it actually involves snaps.

Answer (score 3):

1. Create a new home directory for the second flatpak app instance

```shell
sudo mkdir -p /home/flatpak2
```

2. Ensure that you are the owner of the new dir

```shell
sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /home/flatpak2
```

3. Run the second app instance with this home dir

```shell
env HOME=/home/flatpak2 flatpak run com.microsoft.Teams
```

Comment: no longer works

Note that the directory 

'/home/flatpak2/.local/share/flatpak/exports/share'

is not in the search path set by the XDG_DATA_DIRS environment variable, so
applications installed by Flatpak may not appear on your desktop until the
session is restarted.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a different flatpak `HOME` for each isolated copy you want, like so:

```
env HOME=/path/to/your/custom/flatpak/home flatpak run your-app
```

For example, you can have a couple of scripts to run Zoom and Flatseal isolated from the rest, like so:

```
$ cat zoom.sh
#!/bin/sh
env HOME=$(pwd)/custom-flatpak-home flatpak run us.zoom.Zoom

$ cat flatseal.sh
#!/bin/sh
env HOME=$(pwd)/custom-flatpak-home flatpak run com.github.tchx84.Flatseal
```

Since it took me a while to figure out how to go about doing this I wrote a small blog post about it, feel free to check it out:
https://ivanalejandro0.com/blog/flatpak-custom-data-folder/

Comment: this no longer works.
```
Note that the directory 

'/home/flatpak2/.local/share/flatpak/exports/share'

is not in the search path set by the XDG_DATA_DIRS environment variable, so
applications installed by Flatpak may not appear on your desktop until the
session is restarted.
```